# How to grab a hidden input's attributes using Google Tag Manager Click Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-tag-manager

I have hidden inputs being created dynamically and populated using angularjs like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="input-{{counter_here}}" name="{{dynamic_name_here}}"
    value="dynamic_value_here" />
```

I want to use Google Tag Manager (GTM) to track some data based on the `input`s' attriibutes.

I'm using javascript like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++){
    $('#input-' + i).click();
}
```

... so that I can fire a click event on each of these `input`s (as there could be multiple instances of these `input`s), thereby triggering a tag in GTM.

I know that in GTM I can use the built in variable "Click ID" to get the `id` attribute of the input when clicked. But what I need is the `name` and `value` attributes to be recorded; the `name` in GTM's 'action' and the `value` in GTM's 'label'. GTM's 'value' can be left as default.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've tried using

```
{{Click Element}}.getAttribute('name') // and
{{Click Element}}.getAttribute('value')
```

... like so:

[image]

But when I preview I just get a string returned instead of the values:

[image]

Comment: With your solution you will get an individual event for each form field ( you then can access each field with all its attributes via {{Click Element}}) , so you would not be able to use all the form values in a single tag - is that what you need, or would that be an unwanted side effect ?

Comment: Yes the idea is that if I had 4 inputs, I would have 4 events fired in GTM. And each fire should record the respective `name` and `value` values in the tag's action and label attributes. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that part from my deleted answer is still valid - the click event returns the clicked DOM element (if you use the generic click listener, not the link click listener) and that should go into the {{Click Element}} variable. However instead of triggering a click event you could also push a custom event and your field data to the datalayer. IMO a custom event would be better (since a click event might apply to other tags also).

Comment: How would I use a custom event with more than one input? I can `dataLayer.push({'event': 'dynamic_name_here'})` to get the name value for one input, but what about the value and the same for the second and third input?

Comment: Hi, I am at the office currently - I will try for a decent answer with an example this evening. I do not think the fields are javascript enabled, we will probably fare better by using a custom javascript variable.

Comment: @EikePierstorff is correct. The fields are not Javascript enabled. You have to create custom JavaScript variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Event Action and Event Label are both processed as strings, as you have found out. The easiest solution inline with the approach you are attempting is to create new JavaScript variables for each of the attributes:

[image]

Then update your Event tags with the new JavaScript variables:

[image]

Comment: lol the one thing I didn't try. I was sure that the syntax {{Click Element}} wouldn't register in custom javascript.